# Layering multiple images in 3D-space

Tags: image, matlab, plot, visualization

Suppose we have a matrix I of size 49x49x5, corresponding to 5 images of size 49x49 stacked along the third dimension so we have a total of 5 images. These images should visualize the density of a gas in a 3D space, so we can think of each image as a section cut of the room at different locations.

Is there any way to make a figure in MATLAB where all 5 images are shown as hanging in the 3D space they "came from"?

Here is an image hopefully making it clearer what I am after:
[image: 5 images haning in 3D space]

Comment: What did you use to generate that image?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the following example. It uses the low-level [SURFACE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surface.html) function to plot stacked images:

```
%# create stacked images (I am simply repeating the same image 5 times)
img = load('clown');
I = repmat(img.X,[1 1 5]);
cmap = img.map;

%# coordinates
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(I,2), 1:size(I,1));
Z = ones(size(I,1),size(I,2));

%# plot each slice as a texture-mapped surface (stacked along the Z-dimension)
for k=1:size(I,3)
    surface('XData',X-0.5, 'YData',Y-0.5, 'ZData',Z.*k, ...
        'CData',I(:,:,k), 'CDataMapping','direct', ...
        'EdgeColor','none', 'FaceColor','texturemap')
end
colormap(cmap)
view(3), box on, axis tight square
set(gca, 'YDir','reverse', 'ZLim',[0 size(I,3)+1])
```

I am using indexed color images (with direct color mapping), but it can be easily changed to use grayscale images (with scaled color mapping).

Now if you want to get the 3D space arranged like you have shown in your question, simply interchange the Y and Z dimensions (images stacked along the Y-dimension instead of the Z-dimension).

In general, to have more control on the viewing angle, use the [camera manipulation functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/visualize/f4-5799.html).

[image: screenshot_zstacked_indexed]
[image: screenshot_ystacked_grayscale]

Comment: may i ask how you make five images by loading one?  what about the idea if i have 5 different gpeg images and i want to hang them as in 3d? @Amro

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem in the example above I'm just `repeat`-ing the same image 5 times and stacking them on top of each other. You can obviously read different images in the same manner, as long as they are all of the same size. Also I was using "indexed" images, but you can change it to display either "grayscale" (stacked in the 3rd dim) or "truecolor" images (stacked in the 4th dim). Here is an example for RGB images: http://pastebin.com/T1shKdYF

Comment: thanks for beautiful reply. Yes, i know you just load build in image in matlab, then creates copies of this image by reshaping. Actually i have 3 different gpeg images. These are upper atmospheric weather chats which i want to show as 3d where z axiz will be height in the atmosphere? How After reading these 3 images, then where i do modification in your loving and beautiful code? Please see eykanal's prototype image below. @Amro i am your fan.... I was waiting from a no of days to talk with you. Final you hear my voice...

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem Thanks. Like I showed in the pastebin, stack the images on top of each other. So if you got 3 RGB images, that would be `I = cat(4,img1,img2,img3)`. Also in my example, I'm just using the index `k` as the Z-axis coordinate. So if you have a specific "elevation" for each image, use that instead (i.e replace the `'ZData',Z.*k` part with the correct elevation). If you want further help, it would be better to create a new question, it's not convenient to post answer in the comments. Just be sure to include all the necessary information along with your current code..

Comment: I shall post new question, but before posting i want to know some thing. My .jpg images representing upper atmosphere chats, I have three such chats, of atmosphere at 100m , 200m, 300m height from ground.  My weather chat contians three climatic variables, temperature shown in color map, on this heat map, elevation contours are representing height variable, there is also quver plot which show winds speed and direction at this height. Now i want to pile them in 3d space as eykanal's prototype image below. Tell me whether it will best i make these slices during making these chats ??

Comment: or use .jpg images for stacking them along z axis? my temperature, elevation, winds data was in text file from where i generate this images(chats). Now when i make some modiffications in your beautiful code, it stack three images as i want but all images background becomes **brown** which enable reader to even look at this 3d plot? Tell me please if during making my chats, it is batter to make them slices, then i post according to that new question? @Amro

Comment: please tell me i have not time to wait please @Amro

Comment: here is my question : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019712/how-to-make-a-slice-of-multiple-images-in-3d]

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is the [`patch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch.html) function. By way of example:

```
x=[1 1 6]; y=[2 7 2]; z=[1 1 -1];
```

This specifies a triangle (three points), and the coordinates of the vertices are `(1,2,1)`, `(1,6,1)`, and `(6,2,-1)`. If you would add a fourth point to each vector it would be a rectangle, with the new vertex at the new x,y,z coordinate.

To answer your posted question directly, you can plot a number of rectangles for each variable simply by using a multidimensional array for `x`, `y`, and `z`, where each column specifies a different polygon. In practice, this works as follows:

```
% plot two rectangles
x = [1 1 1 1;
    1 1 1 1;
    4 4 4 4;
    4 4 4 4;];

y = [1 1 1 1;
    2 2 2 2;
    2 2 2 2;
    1 1 1 1;];

z = [1 2 3 4;
    1 2 3 4;
    1 2 3 4;
    1 2 3 4;];

patch(x,y,z,'w');
```

Which makes:

[image: Four stacked rectangles]

There are options you can use to add color to the polygons, check the docs.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood (and my image alone was misleading). I want to fill those patches with images stored in the matrix. Can that be done with patches? I'm checking out slice() now which seems promising.

Comment: @Vidar - Actually, it can, but my example isn't what you're looking for then. Check out the [Patch Properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch_props.html?) page, the CData section.

Comment: @eykanal will you guide me in above Armo answer please

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the [slice()](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/slice.html) or [contourslice()](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/contourslice.html) functions to do this.

Check out this example:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/techniques-for-visualizing-scalar-volume-data.html

Comment: Link broken; Substituted results of searching on that text.