# Matlab's slice() function not working as desired

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, volume-rendering, discrete-space

I want to plot discrete 2D images at 13 `z` locations at `[4:4:52]` using the following lines of code.

```
a=100;
[mesh.x,mesh.y,mesh.z] = meshgrid(1:1:100,1:1:100,4:4:52);
a_unifdist=0;
b_unifdist=10;
noise=a_unifdist+(b_unifdist-a_unifdist).*rand(100,100,13);
c = (a./mesh.x)+noise;
slice(c,1:100,1:100,4:4:52);
```

However, I get 13 continuous plots from 1 till 13 instead of 13 discrete locations as shown below:

[image]

Could somebody tell me what's my mistake? I want the images to stack at `[4:4:52]` locations on z-axis. Thanks.

Comment: related question: [Plotting multiple images in 3D-space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7689586/97160)

Comment: Amro: Thanks. Actually I came to know about the function `slice()` from that post itself. However, that question is with regards to actual images than matrices (which is my problem).

Comment: btw, you shouldn't use `mesh` as a variable name (its already the name of a MATLAB function)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps you meant:

```
slice(mesh.x, mesh.y, mesh.z, c, [], [], 4:4:52)
```

---

Here is a more interesting example than random data:

```
load mri
D = double(squeeze(D));

h = slice(D, [], [], 1:size(D,3));
set(h, 'EdgeColor','none', 'FaceColor','interp')
alpha(.1)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's correct! Apparently, it's giving first three images from bottom as colored, but, the rest of the 10 images as black. How to correct that?

Comment: @S_H: sorry, fixed. If the data is too dense, you can subsample along the x/y directions: `c(1:4:end,1:4:end,:)` and so on for `mesh.x`, `mesh.y` and `mesh.z`

Comment: Amro: I am sorry but I did not understand your last comment. Can you explain what does that mean? I changed the variable name `mesh` to `Grid`.

Comment: @S_H: First of all, I fixed the first line, I hope you saw the edit. Now the slices should render correctly for your case. As to my comment, I simply meant that if you found the plot to be too crowded, try to reduce the resolution of the grid; Instead of generating x/y using `1:100` in the `meshgrid` call, reduce it to say `1:4:100`