# Matlab 3D dose array visualization

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 3D matrix in Matlab which corresponds to an energy dose delivered matrix. I am trying to visualize and represent the matrix. At the moment I am doing the following ([thanks to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318724/matlabs-slice-function-not-working-as-desired)).

```
diff = double(squeeze(diff));
h = slice(diff, [], [], 1:size(diff,3));
set(h, 'EdgeColor','none', 'FaceColor','interp')
alpha(.1)
```

[image]
That gives me a good 3D plot, however it is still difficult to see it properly and I have to keep rotating the figure to be able to visualize it properly. I have also used :

```
isosurface(diff,'isovalue')
```

but again it is hard to see anything.

I was wondering if there is a way of getting rid of the blue area around the actual dose representation since the blue area corresponds to `0` values. Perhaps getting rid of that could help me to see a much more clear picture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can set the zeros to `nan` so that they are not plotted

```
diff = double(squeeze(diff));
diff(diff==0)=nan;                              % added line
h = slice(diff, [], [], 1:size(diff,3));
set(h, 'EdgeColor','none', 'FaceColor','interp')
alpha(.1)
```

### Example

using the MRI data form the previous question

```
load mri
D = double(squeeze(D));
D(D==0)=nan;
h = slice(D, [], [], 1:size(D,3));
set(h, 'EdgeColor','none', 'FaceColor','interp')
alpha(.1)
```

### output

*with replacing zeros with nan*
[image]
*without replacing zeros with nan*
[image]

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to make a copy of the data with the values you don't want represented by NaN.  For example, here is the original example image from the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11319175/2092048)

[image]

Now if we take the same set of image data, replace zeros with `NaN` and plot using the same method:

```
D(D==0)=NaN;
h = slice(D, [], [], 1:size(D,3));
set(h, 'EdgeColor','none', 'FaceColor','interp')
alpha(.1)
```

[image]

Comment: SNAP! even down to the plots

Comment: Talk about "twin-solutions" :) +1 to both.