# how to make a slice of multiple images in 3d in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, slice

I have these three images meterology. First image is weather chat of 100m, second is of 200m, thrid is of 300m

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is roughly prototype of my idea what i want

[image]

Both longitude and latitude are same in three images, I want to just makes longitude as x - axis, latitude as y axis and 100m image at 100, 200m image at 200 ....

With @Armo on this [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689586/layering-multiple-images-in-3d-space/7714270?noredirect=1#comment63374970_7714270) , i able to producce this code,

```
a=imread('100.jpg');
b=imread('200.jpg');
c=imread('300.jpg');
I = cat(4,a,b,c);
data = importdata('gpheight300.txt') ;
x = data(:,1) ; x = unique(x) ;  
y = data(:,2) ; y = unique(y) ; 
%# coordinates
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(I,2), 1:size(I,1));
%[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z = ones(size(I,1),size(I,2));
kin=[100 200 300];

for k=1:length(kin)
   surface('XData',X, 'YData',Y, 'ZData',Z.*kin(k), ...
        'CData',I(:,:,k), 'CDataMapping','direct', ...
        'EdgeColor','none', 'FaceColor', 'texturemap')
      %  patch('XData',X, 'YData',Y, 'ZData',Z.*kin(k),'CData',I(:,:,k))
end
%colormap(cmap)
view(3), box on, %axis tight square
%set(gca, 'YDir','reverse', 'ZLim',[0 size(I,3)+1])
saveas(gcf,'3d','jpg');
```

This code producing surface in which all three images becomes brown color destorying all information on my these three images.

[image]

when i save them just is appear.This code use surface , please can body edit this to my requirement. [image]

**I want to hang these images in horizontally as i shown in prototype. I want x,y - remains , x,y-axis of images, while z becomes axis for elevation. Place 100m image at 100m, 200m image(second one from start) at 200m and 300m on 300m.**

Please some body guide me I shall be very thankful to you on this kind favor always

Comment: Please do not delete and repost [the same question you asked a few days back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019712/how-to-make-a-slice-of-multiple-images-in-3d]). It may help you to think why that question never gathered much attention. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I need solution of this simple question. That why i regenerate new thread removing all the previous... No of times if I do not able to got answer within a day them my question remains in request of solution for 6 months at then I have to answered my own question

Comment: Can you post the files for your 3 images ?

Comment: The difference in your original images and these ones is the colormap limits. Try to change that

Comment: @Ratbert thanks for your reply. Tell me if you do not mind, i have uploaded my files associated with these images on  here [mathwork central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/292262#comment_375652)

Comment: @AnderBiguri , I do not get your point of view? What are my original images please? I think you can do more understanding of my question after getting [data set](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/292262#comment_375652)  i used?

Comment: What I say is, the images are probably rigth, its just the colormap is saturated.

Comment: yes actually its background becomes brown. I use surf function , may be it is due to this?

Comment: how can i corrrect it ? @AnderBiguri

Comment: Your code doesnt work because your images re not indexed images. Please, take your time, read the code **you are using** and **understand it**. That will help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115843/discussion-between-muhammad-usman-saleem-and-ander-biguri).

Comment: I am still unable to solve this question

Comment: still not able to solve this problem. I think i have to answered my own question again